# Convert date format on HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I try to convert a String that contains for example `28-11-2015` to put it as **default** value on html **date input** but to do this it must be like that `2015-11-28`

HTML / JAVA / JEE / SQL
NB: The String is request value of another input that it have been inserted by the user.

`<input type="date" value="${date_rv}" name="date_rv_i" readonly ><br>`

[image: This is the result]

> And this is what I want

[image]

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you need to parse the date in one format, and format it in another. There are *lots* of questions about parsing and formatting dates from Java. Look for those, and try the answers. If you still have difficulties, put what you've tried and what went wrong into your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have try a lot of edition to covert the input to date with the format that i want and return it to string but it not work

Comment: Well you should show what you've tried and what happened then.

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution if using HTML only **(No way with HTML alone)**
i think you should use jquery
the suitable jquery plugin is [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

OR you can use [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible,See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/3143384

You can use jquery [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). It provides many option, also your required date format.